# How to stack text (Sentences) under the previous sentence in a text field?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, stack

i am a big time nood. I am trying to make an app but i can not configure the text field to stack the users text under the previous text instead of just running off to the right in a never ending line. PLEASE HELP! I need more then just a code. Where do i put it??? Witch file? Thanks!

Please this is holding me back!

Answer (score 0):

You can put newline characters into the textView's text property:

```
self.textView.text = @"Foo\nBar";
```

You'll get 'Foo' on the first line and 'Bar' on the second.

Comment: How do i go about using this code? Im sorry man im a noob :( Can you give me really short instructions and which file to put it in? Thanks! :)

Comment: How did you get the non-working text into the text field?  You can do the same thing, but include a \n newline character.